# How to sum a result of array with another array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

```
var BasicSizeArr = [350, 320, 300];
var SecondSizeArr = [30, 35, 40];
function ChangeImg(imgPtr) {
document.getElementById("basic").innerHTML = BasicSizeArr[imgPtr];
}
function ChangeSize(size) {
document.getElementById("sizes").innerHTML = SecondSizeArr[size];
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" value="0" onclick="ChangeImg(this.value)"/><img src="images/b1.jpg"/>
<input type="radio" value="1" onclick="ChangeImg(this.value)"/><img src="images/b2.jpg"/>
<div id="basic"></div>
<select id="size" name="size">
<option id="30x145" value="0" onclick="ChangeSize(this.value)">30 x 145 MM</option>                                 
<option id="35x155" value="1" onclick="ChangeSize(this.value)">35 x 155 MM</option>
```

```
<div id="sumsize"></div>
```

I want to sum each value of SecondSizeArr of numbers with value of BasicSizeArr[imgPtr], 
so if i got 350, the result would be

var new SecondSizeArr = [380, 385, 390];

The BasicSizeArr comes from image-radiobuttons, the SecondSizeArr with optionbuttons...

Can anyone think of a way? Any idea...?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you considered a `for` loop?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but this question has been asked [multiple times](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=pGquVoCjE-OI8QfDjqWABw#q=site:stackoverflow.com+sum+two+arrays+javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with `Array.map()`:

```
var BasicSizeArr = [350, 320, 300];
var SecondSizeArr = [30, 35, 40];
var SecondSizeArrSummed; 

function ChangeImg(imgPtr) {
    document.getElementById("basic").innerHTML = BasicSizeArr[imgPtr];
    SecondSizeArrSummed = SecondSizeArr.map(function(v){
        return v + BasicSizeArr[imgPtr]; 
    });
}

console.log(new_SecondSizeArrSummed );   // [380, 385, 390]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for-loop:

```
var BasicSizeArr = [350, 320, 300];
var SecondSizeArr = [30, 35, 40];

var summedArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < BasicSizeArr.length; i++) {
    summedArr.push(BasicSizeArr[i] + SecondSizeArr[i]);
}

console.log(summedArr); // Array [ 380, 355, 340 ]
```